# Using 3 different communication protocols in the same MCU

Tags: serial-port, ethernet, can-bus

For a project I need to make communicate in a CANBus network, ethernet network and with RS-232. I want to use one single MCU that will act as the main unit of CANBus start topology, Ethernet start topology and that MCU also will be transfering the RS232 data that comes to it to another device. Now I want to use high speed CAN which can be up to 1 Mbits per second. However,RS-232 is max 20 k baud. I wonder if it is doable with 1 MCU to handle 3 different communications ( CANBus, ethernet and RS-232). I am afraid of to get overrun with data at some point. I can buffer data short term if data comes in bursts that can be averaged out. For continuous data where I'll never be able to keep up, I'll need to discard messages, perhaps in a managed way. But I do not want to discard any data. So my question is: Would using 1 MCU for this case work? And are there any software tricks that would help me with this case? (Like giving CANBus a higher priority etc.)

Comment: You need to write a specification that addresses real-time requirements. How much data is sent, at which speed, and how fast does it need to be handled, what's the response time of the system and so on.

Comment: There will be 4 Can diagnostic messages, that at 1 Mbit, and I need to process them as fast as I can. RS-232 line will be 9600 baud and 10Mbit ethernet I guess.

Comment: That's not much of a real-time spec. Baudrates don't say much, what matters is how frequently you send/receive data and how much time you have to process whatever it is that the program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with a single MCU. Even a simple MCU should easily be able to handle data rates of 1 Mbps. Most likely you want to use DMA enabled transfer so the CPU core will only need to act when the transmission of a chunk of data has completed.

The problem of being overrun by data due to the mismatch in data rate is a separate topic:

- If the mismatch persists, no system can handle it, no matter how capable.
- If the mismatch is temporary, it's just a function of the available buffer size.

So if the worst case you want to handle is 10s of incoming data at 1 Mbps (with an outgoing rate of 20kbps), then you will need 10s x (1Mbps - 20kps) = 9.8 Mbit = 1.225 MByte of buffer memory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and what do you mean by "DMA enabled transfer"?

Comment: DMA (or direct memory access) is a feature of most MCUs (except very low range ones) for automatically transferring data from peripherals such as UART or CAN to memory or vice versa. It can be configured such that hundreds of bytes of data are transmitted over or received by a peripheral without involving the CPU core. It will be notified when the transmission is complete. It's also very valuable because it allows several transmissions in parallel.

Comment: So it reduces CPU usage I guess. Does it also reduce the memory usage in a relative way?

Comment: It reduces CPU usage and increases parallelism. But it does not reduce memory usage, which is given by the data rate difference and the maximum time for buffering.